# Unable to hide the img using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

here is my code-snippet:

```
    <div id="navbar">
        <a href="index.html" >
        <img class="navbar" src="http://ssss.com/imgs/WG_home.png" />
        </a>Home
    </div>



    function used to hide:

    $(document).ready(function() { 
     alert("hello");
    if (location.search=="?value=nohome")
       {
        $("img[class='navbar']").hide();
       }

 });
```

Any one having any idea how to hide the image?

mrana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$('.navbar']).hide();
```

make use of class selector insted of the selector you use ..

**EDIT**

To hide only one image out of 10-15 image with the same class , in that case you cannot go for class selector you need to make use of id selector which uniquelly identify the image...`("#id").hide();`

Comment: actually i have 10-15 more images with same and just want to hide one of them. Is there any way to uniquely identify the one which i want to hide i.e id or something?

Comment: @mrana - in that case you cannot go for class selector you need to make use of id selector which uniquelly identify the image...("#id").hide();

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("nohome") >= 0)
{
   $("img.navbar").hide(); // changed...........
}
```

Notice that instead of `$("img[class='navbar']")`, you can simply use `$("img.navbar")` or `$(".navbar")` if `navbar` is applied only on images you want to target.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

if (location.href.indexOf("nohome") >= 0)
   {
    $("img[class='navbar']").hide();
   }
```

});​

Here is the
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parush/5Sqg9/)